# Dockerize TypeScript written NodeJs express Application

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, heroku

I have written a NodeJS Application in TypeScript. during the development, this is how I maintain my `npm script` in the `package.json`

```
  "main": "dist/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon src/server.ts",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

because of Dockerizing i have done below modification,

```
    "main": "dist/server.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node dist/src/server.js",
        "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
```

> Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install -g typescript
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
RUN tsc
CMD ["node", "start"]
```

> docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  api:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 4001:4001
    environment:
      PORT: 4001
      MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING: mongo_path
```

I used the below commands to create a docker

```
docker build -t app-backend .  
heroku container:push web -a app-backen
heroku container:release web -a app-backen
```

the error I'm getting

```
2023-08-12T10:20:57.165570+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node start`
2023-08-12T10:20:57.716969+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Exec format error
2023-08-12T10:20:57.835560+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 126
2023-08-12T10:20:57.866670+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

what went wrong with this approach? Thanks in advance

Comment: The Docker image contains a copy of the `node` binary and other supporting tools.  Are you maybe building on an ARM-based system but deploying to an x86 host?